# How can I clean up Boolean operations?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, topology, artifacts

[image: Results]

[image]

I'm trying to create a mesh as shown in the image. The best way I could think to do this was to use the Boolean modifier, which looks nice shaded flat. However, this creates a messy topology with several large n-gons which causes unsightly artifacts when smooth-shaded. 

I was wondering how one could create proper topology from this. Or is using a Boolean modifier the wrong way to go about it? I'm pretty new to Blender and 3D modeling as a whole so I would love to hear how someone more experienced than me would create a shape such as this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could bevel the angles and try to keep quads instead of ngons. Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've uploaded the file. I'm not sure how I would go about keeping quads with this kind of mesh though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

- First apply the Scale on your object because if you've scaled your object in *Object* mode the bevels won't give anything good.
- Only keep the front face.
- Use the knife to create quads all over your plane: <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly.
- Make sure you don't have vertices very close to each other, if so use merge, remove doubles.
- Extrude.
- Give your object a *Subsurf* modifier and smooth it.
- Bevel the drawings edges.
- Bevel the border edges.
- Cut an edge loop with the knife along the background face (or mirror the front face so that you don't have to work the back).
- Clean all the corners.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!